# Open up in a tab not a window

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open url in new tab using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

I'm trying to make it so that something opens up in a tab, not a window. As far as I can tell, this is set by browser preference. Is there no real way to override this? I understand you can use window.open, but is this subject to browser preference? I'm currently using target="_blank".

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4907843/330494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following CSS:

```
a {
    target-name: new;
    target-new: tab;
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/aSYZB/) (please not it does not work because jsFiddle does not support tabs. It is merely for demonstration purposes)

As simple one line solution:

```
<a href="http://www.bbc.com" target="new" style="target-name:new;target-new:tab">
    Text
</a>​
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is really no way for you to have it open in a new tab instead of a new window. It is, as you said, a browser preference.

As to jacktheripper's response. It looks like the target-name property is not supported in any major browser*.

*[CSS3 target-name Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_target-name.asp)